# How many Multichannel Mixer audio units can you use in an iOS 4.0 application?

Tags: iphone

How many Multichannel Mixer audio units can you use simultaneously in an iOS 4.0 application?  Is there a hard limit to this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard limit per se, but you do approach the limits of the device eventually.  I did some testing, and [reported the results here](http://atastypixel.com/blog/pushing-multichannelmixer-to-the-limit/).